# How should yarn properties be configured for a fair scheduler?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

My applications are not getting accepted by YARN.  When I launch them, they don't fail, but they just hang for forever (they don't get the ever-so-common `ACCEPTED` either).

I have a cluster of 25 nodes, each with 60 G of memory and 8 cores.

I set up two queues in my `fair-scheduler.xml` file, each allocated (at the maximum) 600 GB and 100 cores.

From my calculation, 60G * 25 nodes should be more than enough resources to support both queues.  Also, the 8 cores * 25 nodes should be plenty to support one job running in a queue with 100 cores.

When I check the YARN ui at port 8088 It shows that all of the nodes have 60 G of memory available and 7 vcores available. But it shows no applications running and no applications accepted.

When I check the spark web UI at port 4040 I am able to see my jobs getting picked up.  But why won't YARN acknowledge them so that I can use the fair scheduler as it was intended?

I tried restarting the `hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager`.  Is there another setting I have to change?

how do I get the fair scheduler to accept my job?

*EDIT* after a long time I get the message `Lost executor...Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues`.

Which thresholds am I exceeding?

Comment: Maybe check `yarn.scheduler.fair.locality.threshold.node` e.g. in [this link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html). Also, in which queue are you launching spark? Cheers.

Comment: I have only two queues, *A* and *B*.  Does `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` have anything to do with it?  I thought this was set dynamically by the fair scheduler so I didn't bother changing it.  Same for `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb spark`?

Comment: Sure, you have to allocate memory to your containers. Anyway, my question about the queue when launching was because of the parameter --queue in spark-submit

Comment: My two applications are each running in different queues.  Is that acceptable?  I'd interested in more information about those yarn properties.  @Irnzcig can you help me with that?

Comment: Sure, I'd be glad to help, but what is it exactly that you need? Did you make your jobs work finally? I've configured a fair scheduler before, but I was using a Cloudera distribution, so I did not have to write the `xml` manually... As for the memory parameters of yarn, yes you have to set them. Anyway, reading again your question, you should not look to the scheduling as a way to support the workload of your queues, but rather the opposite. Point is, if your cluster gets to the limit of its resources, how the resources are going to be split between queues? => that's scheduling...

Comment: ... i.e. if one job is alone in the cluster it can get all the resources it needs, regardless of how you define the queues. Hope it helps somehow, but anyway, if you nail down your question, I can definitively try to help. There's many resources online anyway, for example [this](https://mapr.com/blog/best-practices-yarn-resource-management) is a good summary coming from MapR, each distribution has theirs. Good luck.

Comment: I specifically want to know what `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` and `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` do to affect my jobs.  They seem to be important but I haven't figured out how to configure them.